# get sum of the 3 sorted numbers from a user inputted list

Tags: python

i recently started to learn python and i wrote this code to sort numbers least to greatest inputted by the user but after the second number, i get the error "NameError: name 'minimum' is not defined" any help is appreciated. also, I cannot use any built-in functions to sort the numbers as this is a challenge for a class

```
unsorted_list = []
sorted_list = []

while True:
  unsortednum = input("enter a number or 0 to stop: ")
  if unsortednum == 0:
    while unsorted_list:
     minimum = unsorted_list[0]
  for item in unsorted_list:
        if item < minimum:
            minimum = item
        sorted_list.append(minimum)
        unsorted_list.remove(minimum)
   
    print(sorted_list)
  else:
    unsorted_list.append(unsortednum)
```

Comment: You get that error if `minimum = unsorted_list[0]` never ran by the time `for item in unsorted_list` started. Meaning that `if unsortednum == 0:` never returned `True`. You never handle that case, since you haven't specified what `minimum` should be if it was never set in the above code.

Comment: what happens if your input is not a number, do you ignore the value? Note that input statement will always be accepted as string. You need to convert it to number if you want to do comparison.

Comment: python has sort() and sorted() to help you sort. If you want to use that, it would be faster. If you are trying to learn to code and apply sort logic, then OK

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do it.

```
sorted_list = []
while True:
  # The input you get is a string so you need to convert it to int
  unsortednum = int(input("enter a number or 0 to stop: "))
  # Use break to exit if the user input's 0
  if unsortednum == 0:
    break
  else:
    # This first creates a list of all numbers lesser than equal to unsortednum then joins the first list with a second list
    # that only contains unsortednum. After that a third list with all numbers greater than unsortednum is joined as well.
    sorted_list = [i for i in sorted_list if i <= unsortednum] + [unsortednum] + [i for i in sorted_list if i > unsortednum];
  print("Current => ",sorted_list)
print("Final => ",sorted_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing the least amount of editing to your code:

```
unsorted_list = []
sorted_list = []

while True:
  unsortednum = int(input("enter a number or 0 to stop: "))
  if unsortednum == 0:
    while unsorted_list:
      minimum = unsorted_list[0]
      for item in unsorted_list[1:]:
        if item < minimum:
          minimum = item
      sorted_list.append(minimum)
      unsorted_list.remove(minimum)
   
    print(sorted_list)
  else:
    unsorted_list.append(unsortednum)
```

The only thing missing was assigning unsortednum as an int done by `unsortednum = int(input())`
Also, in order to not check a value with itself, in the for loop I changed `unsorted_list` to `unsorted_list[1:]`, representing every value in the list except `unsorted_list[0]`